# Unable to generate query to fetch jenkins job for a given execution with Harness

Tags: graphql, cicd, tap-harness, maven-plugin-testing-harness

Can someone please help me out in generating a GraphQL Query for fetching the details of Jenkins Job URL added at a verify stage under Deployment Phases in a given workflow?

Below is the documentation for the same,
https://developer.harness.io/docs/first-gen/firstgen-platform/techref-category/api/harness-api/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by enabling `Jenkins Output in the Context` option at Configure your Jenkins job and then also add a variable name like, `Jenkins_Test` with scope as `Workflow`.

In Workflow variables, add a variable as like, `Jenkins_Test_Config` with value as, `${context.Jenkins_Test.buildUrl}`.

In the Workflow Overview, add Tags as below,
`Jenkins_Test_Config:${workflow.variables.Jenkins_Test_Config}`

and the same below GraphQL query can be used as below,

```
{
  execution(executionId: "<EXECUTION-ID>") {
    ... on WorkflowExecution {
      tags {
        name
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```